# Deleting a row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to delete a row from my list. However the program crashes everytime I do so.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.logList removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (5)
>   must be equal to the number of rows
>   contained in that section before the
>   update (5), plus or minus the number
>   of rows inserted or deleted from that
>   section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

So can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it necessary for me to update the number of rows that the datasource-method returns? And how would I do that if this is the case.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [tv beginUpdates];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.logList removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        [tv endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you put in the - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method ?

Comment: I do not have anything there, should I write 1?

Comment: you should return [self.logList count] in order to give to your tableView always the exact count of its rows